# How to use a macrovariable as string?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to do the following request :

```
data _null_;    
  call symputx("test",findw(' x y z ','x'));    
run;
```

using a macrovariable instead of the
 `' x y z '` part, i.e.

```
data _null_;    
  call symputx("test",findw(&mv,'x'));    
run;
```

where mv is a macrovariable, whose value is calculated by a macro-function that I can't modify. Let's assume that this value is :

```
%let mv=x y z;
```

My problem is that if mv does not contain quotation marks, the code won't work :

```
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.
```

I tried to add them using `%str` (again, I can't modify the way mv is calculated so I have to use `&mv`):

```
%let mv2=%str(%') &mv %str(%');
```

and using `%put`, I can see that mv2 value is `'x y z'`
But I get a similar error as before (not quite the same):

```
ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.
```

If y try with `%let mv=' x y z ';`, it works but I can't do such a thing as I have to use `&mv` (or can I ?).

I don't understand what's wrong, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro variables are just text fills.  The macro variable needs to be a legal SAS value in the data step.

```
%let mv=123;
data _null_;
x="&mv";
put x=;
run;
```

For example.  `"` (double quotes) resolve macro variables, `'` (single quotes) do not.

In your example, you can also do this without the symput.

```
%let mv2 = %sysfunc(findw(&mv,x,,ios))
```

Important details: SYSFUNC doesn't take quotes for any parameters (it would consider the quote a character, not to be quoting anything), and with findw specifically if it is space delimited you need a way to get space in that field as leaving a blank space doesn't work.  FINDW has some specific issues also related to the fact that it has multiple structures with numeric and character optional arguments.

Comment: Knowing that difference between ' and " will be much usefull,thanks a lot !